# How to become an astronaut?

Tags: spacecraft, astronauts, astronomy

I am a pure/applied mathematics student at Tehran University. About 2 or 3 years later I will get my bachelor's degree and start studying master's in applied math or theoretical physics. And maybe I will apply for an American or Canadian university to continue my way.

So wanna ask you if I want to be an astronaut, what should I do to be a candidate in the space organizations? Can anyone help me?

Comment: Too broad?? I think, "too narrow" would match the reality better. However, explaining how narrow is it, could be an acceptable answer. I suggest "leave open".

Comment: You may look for some [astronauts'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_astronauts_by_name) formation and career. You can see there are quite different formation ([some](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Claudie_Haigner%C3%A9) have a PhD in biology, [others](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean-Pierre_Haigner%C3%A9) are former test pilots,...)

Comment: Related: https://space.stackexchange.com/q/10548/6944

Answer (score 5):

Currently, if you want to become an astronaut for a traditional space agency (i.e. NASA, ESA, Roscosmos) you basically need to be a citizen of that country or in ESA's case, a citizen of one of the [ESA Member States](https://www.esa.int/About_Us/Corporate_news/Member_States_Cooperating_States).

In the USA, the most reliable method of becoming a NASA astronaut is to be a military test pilot and eventually cross over to NASA. If you want to apply as a flight engineer or scientist, you need to **be very lucky** and distinguish yourself in your field somehow.

Realistically, if you want to be a space agency sponsored astronaut, you need to be extremely lucky, dedicated, and skilled. Setting your career goal as "become an astronaut" isn't a wise move as it's setting yourself up for failure.

The easiest way to become an astronaut today is to become rich. It's a pretty safe bet to say that in 20 years, space tourism will be far bigger than today and even now, if you've got a couple dozen million dollars laying about, it's doable.

Comment: And even if you do get into the position that may land you astronaut, you need so many physiological qualifications too. You can't be hitting 150 bpm during a rocket launch.

Comment: ESA os not an EU agency, there's overlap but not all EU members are in  ESA and, conversely, not all participants in ESA are EU countries.

Comment: Thanks for you help

Comment: Is test pilot still an extremely common background for NASA astronauts? I thought it was less important in the shuttle and post-shuttle era. e.g. STS-127 in 2009, only 2 of 6 American crew members were test pilots; the others had multiple engineering and/or MD degrees.

Comment: I made an update to address Diego's comment. Here's the source for the fact that only ESA Member State citizens can be astronauts: http://www.esa.int/Science_Exploration/Human_and_Robotic_Exploration/Astronauts/How_to_become_an_astronaut.