# Is it possible for a petroleum engineering graduate to become an astronaut? If not, why so? If I can, what should I learn or do then?

Tags: astronauts, career, astronaut-recruitment

So the question pretty much says it all. I would really appreciate it if you guys can give some detailed explanations here for why I might or might not be able to become an astronaut. And also, feel free to ask me questions.

EDIT

Ok, so the thing is that I'm studying petroleum engineering. But I am starting to feel like my motivations for coming into this field are fading away and my focus now is diverting to well, being an astronaut. I know it sounds crazy and whatnot. But the thing is. I really really want to at least give it a shot. And when I say being an astronaut. I mean being an astronaut either in NASA or SpaceX. I know that my field is way far away from what astronauts do but if I want to give a shot. What should I start learning, do?

For example, should I do a master's in mechanical engineering, aeronautical engineering, get fit, learn new engineering skills such as Solidworks, programming, etc. Like what do I do to make my shot even possible?

Comment: Are you talking about NASA astronauts? Have you read the criteria on the NASA website? Which criteria do you not meet? If you meet the criteria, you could theoretically get hired.

Comment: I don't know what it takes to become an astronaut, but IMO, you should not accept that your degree defines what you _are_. Think of it as something that you have _accomplished_. Hey! I bet that wasn't easy. If you are the kind of person who can earn an engineering degree, then just imagine what _else_ you could accomplish if you apply yourself to the challenge.

Comment: Yes - it is possible. But the type of degree is potentially irrelevant. Look at what astronaut programmes are available in your country.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to become an astronaut?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/36825/how-to-become-an-astronaut)

Comment: NASA astronauts have been pro football players, state troopers, and elementary school teachers. Please check the criteria on the website, there is no other answer. https://www.nasa.gov/audience/forstudents/postsecondary/features/F_Astronaut_Requirements.html

Comment: Everything is possible, although it might have a low chance. Currently, even if you birth in the USA, you have a lesser chance to become an astronaut ever, than that you will be hit by a lightning in your life. Being an engineer, it hugely increases your chance. If you are not a born U.S. citizen, it strongly decreases. That your qualification has probably near-zero relation with the space industry, also decreases. The sum is in my opinion, that your chance if hugely bigger than that you will be hit by a lightning, but still too low to build career hopes on that.

Comment: I don't know how well it would fly there, but there is [The Workplace Stack Exchange](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: You definitely did "Add details and clarify the problem being solved" and that would "help others answer the question" except that I think this is still off-topic because it's so specifically about *you* and not about spaceflight or astronautics or astronauts.