# Space exploration career opportunities for Europeans?

Tags: esa, career

My goal is to establish a career in space exploration. What opportunities are there in Europe and how can I best prepare?

I am willing to do all it takes to maximise my chances of working in this area, even if it means going to University again to get another degree (I have a Humanities degree).

I really want to help accelerate our multiplanetary future and would be grateful for any advice.

Comment: I graduated from Spacemaster in 2009, http://www.spacemaster.eu, but you won't get in with a humanities degree, you need a BSc in physics, electronics, mathematics, mechanical engineering, or other STEM.

Comment: Related: [Becoming an astronaut with engineering background](http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/12998/becoming-an-astronaut-with-engineering-background/13034#13034) (location is more general, but is specific to engineers wishing to become astronauts)

Comment: Thanks for your comments everyone. @called2voyage I should clarify that I'm not only interested in becoming an astronaut, just any jobs that help accelerate our multiplanetary future.

Comment: My advice would be to keep in mind the fact that even companies like ESA and NASA need people with backgrounds other than math and science.  They always need their fair share of secretaries, HR personnel, lawyers, and even medical doctors.

With a humanities degree, I would say that you are probably well suited to communication.  That may not be communicating with space teams, but could be inter-agency communication, keeping people connected in the workplace, or helping talk about scientific discoveries to the public.