# How can I become an astronaut?

Tags: astronauts, engineering, isro, electronics, career

For EU citizens to envisage a career in space, as an astronaut, the following [ESA handbook gives details about the selection process](https://esamultimedia.esa.int/docs/careers/ESA_Astrosel_Handbook.pdf).

Similar information for US citizens can be found at this [NASA site](https://www.nasa.gov/stem-ed-resources/how-to-be-an-astronaut.html)

What would be the selection process for India?

Comment: https://www.isro.gov.in/careers

Comment: Good luck; study hard!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Becoming an astronaut with engineering background](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/12998/becoming-an-astronaut-with-engineering-background)

Answer (score 3):

At least in the near future, they will mostly be recruiting from the Indian Air Force. So prepare for AFCAT.

There is another way - earn lot of money.

It is speculated that a single seat in a free-flyer SpaceX Dragon costs over $25M

https://twitter.com/DJSnM/status/1439470685064073219
With Starship, that figure could drastically come down (an order of magnitude lower than Dragon).

Comment: Can you give a source for the claim, that Starship cost per passenger could be an order of magnitude lower compare to Crew Dragon. With Starship you don't need build new CD service module and F9 upper stage after every flight. Only refurbish (or inspect) Super heavy booster and Starship upper stage. Are there some other high fixed costs in human spaceflight unrelated to refurbishing used launch vehicle. For example cost of training for the mission, cost of insurance and etc.